# Combine the ranking

Tags: ranking

I have a table to decide what is the top rank subgroup. My idea is to rank independently into each feature (score, quality) then sum the rank to have the final score (see picture below)

I am not sure it's a good idea. Other idea I could think is to have a score which is averaged by both normalized score and quality (of course they should be normalized e.g. min-max to have same scale). Are there any other commonly used approaches?
[image: Sample Data]

Answer (score 0):

Other approaches could be:

1. Weighted averages of normalized ranks, assuming you know that one features is more important than the other
2. Convert ranks into percentiles and then compute an average (weighted or otherwise) across the features